# Is Comment Converter available on sites other than DBA Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, robots, convert-to-answer

I have just seen [an automatic answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/235132/revisions) being put for one of [my questions on DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/165966/how-does-one-investigate-the-performance-of-a-bulk-insert-statement/235132#235132). This was made by [Comment Converter](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/126897/comment-converter) which seems to be quite useful as [it already got a gold badge](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/badges/49/populist?userid=126897).

The user profile indicated DBA as the only community. Is this used only for DBA or are there any other instances for other communities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to prove a negative but I haven't encountered any other sites in the network where such a bot is active. Comments get converted to (sometimes wiki) answers all the time, but usually under the 'main' account of the user.

This particular account (not a bot, confirmed by the author) is run by [one of the ♦ moderators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1192/paul-white); this has the additional benefit that he's able to delete the comment himself. (Though when run by a normal user, it could still flag the comment as 'no longer needed'.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It *seems* like something which is doable with a userscript, i.e. the user would need to spot comments eligible for conversion, but with a button to do the conversion itself automatically.

Comment: @PaulWhite - I was just wondering if it was bot or human, because it should have been a damn good robot at doing natural language processing.